# Popen disk write cache

Tags: python

I have kind of a newbie question regarding python and disk writes.  Basically I am executing some popen processes in sequence where the second process takes output from the first as its input file.  For example:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["mysqldump", "--single-transaction", "-u",
    database_username, "--password="+database_password, "--databases",
    "--host", server_address, database_name, ],
    stdout = open( outputfile, 'w') , stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
error = p.stderr.read()
```

Then

```
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["tar", "-C", backup_destination,
    "--remove-files", "--force-local", "-czf", gzipoutputfile,
    mysqlfilename ], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
error2 = p2.stderr.read()
```

This *usually* finishes fine in sequence without any problems.  Note that the second process reads from the file the first process generates.  Every once in a while I'll get an error on the second subprocess that says "tar: host-ucpsom_2012-2014-08-05-0513.mysql: file changed as we read it".

I am assuming this is because there are some cached disk writes from the first process, and that the file is actually being finished written to disk after the first process is actually terminated and no longer in memory.

So, my question is; is there an elegant way to wait for cached disk writes to be completed before actually reading from this file? One thing I thought was to read the size of the file on disk, wait a couple of seconds, then check the size of the file again, then if they are the same assume it's being done written, but I feel that there has to be a more elegant way to solve this problem.  Would anybody be able to advise in this regard?  I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: If you call `p.wait()` before invoking p2, you can be sure that all content has been flushed to the VFS layer (not necessarily to disk, but VFS is all you need to avoid this error). If you still get the error when invoking `p2` after being able to read `p.returncode`, you can be confident that something outside of `p` is causing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `p.wait()` (or another call which indirectly waits for exit, such as `communicate()`) before invoking `p2`.

Calling only `p.stderr.read()` waits for `p` to close its stderr channel; however, a program can close its stderr before closing the rest of its file descriptors (which is, for each individual file handle, the step that triggers flush to the VFS layer) and exiting.

If your filesystem is NFS on Linux, ensure that that the `sync` flag is in use (contrast w/ the default `async`), such that operations are complete on the remote end before the local end proceeds.

Comment: Hi, Charles, thank you for your detailed reply.  I have tried what you suggested p.wait() and then echoed the return code, and I am still experiencing the same problem.  I've copied my current code block to a gist so that you can see it. One thing that I thought might be worthwhile to mention is that I am writing to an NFS mount.  Do you think that this would come to play?   I would think this would be abstracted away by the kernel.  Anyway, my gist is here. https://gist.github.com/dsulli99/f22b381ab71c4ac4576c Thank you again for all of your help.

Comment: Also for what it is worth, I am trying communicate() as well, although assuming it is going to fail in the same manner.  I will report back when I have some results.

Comment: @dps NFS is and has always been full of bugs, but tuning your mount flags should allow for workarounds (in particular, `mount -o sync` is your friend here). I was going to suggest using sysdig to inspect the flow of events (it can be asked, for instance, to log all syscalls across all processes on the system touching specific files, unlike strace which has more performance overhead and logs only specific processes), but since some of the events can be happening on other machines (yay, NFS!) it's a bit less useful here.

Comment: ...the short answer is that NFS on Linux trades away safety for performance unless explicitly told to do otherwise. (You'll notice, in testing, that the performance hit from `mount -o sync` is rather large).

Comment: Charles than you for your input.  To be perfectly honest I'm not about to pull my hair out digging through sysdig to debug syscalls across processes.  I expect this to 'just work', if anything I'll just try writing to a local volume then moving the file in a separate command.  Anyway, I'l try the mount -o sync option as well.  Thank you again, I will report back my findings.

Comment: The move command won't necessarily be synchronous either -- though if you're talking about moving the files onto NFS _after_ you've generated the tarball, then yes, that should work.

Comment: Yeah, I'm talking about moving it after the tarball is generated.  I'd actually like an elegant solution, I will try the -o sync as I'm not really concerned with the performance hit at this time.  I'll let you know how it goes.  If nothing else doing it to a local physical disk will help point the finger at NFS.  Thanks again.

Comment: -o sync was eventually the silver bullet that killed this problem once and for all.  thank you for your help.

Comment: @dps, glad to hear that worked; I've updated the answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a file-blocking flag. Once shut down the first process to free the flag file and it will be a sign that the work of the first process is completed.